# Deleting file in shared drive using php results in permission error

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm uploading a zip file to a shared drive but since I don't want it to be duplicated before uploading it I'm trying to delete it.

The upload works fine. But the delete results in an error:

`Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: { “error”: { “code”: 403, “message”: “The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.“, “errors”: [ { “message”: “The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.“, “domain”: “global”, “reason”: “insufficientFilePermissions” } ] } }`

I'm the administrator of the shared drive so I have all the permission.

Here is my code:

```
require '../vendor/autoload.php';

if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE)
    session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();

// credenziali google e scope
$client->setClientId('client id');
$client->setClientSecret('client secret');
$client->setRedirectUri('redirect puri');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));

if (isset($_GET['code']) || (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token'])) {
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    } 
    else
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
    
    $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

    //HERE WAS THE CODE TO GET THE NAME OF THE FILE
    // ----

    //check if file exists
    $optParams = array(
        'pageSize' => 1000,
        'supportsAllDrives' => true,
        'includeItemsFromAllDrives' => true,
        'driveId' => '***', // id of shared drive
        'corpora' => 'drive',
        'fields' => 'files(id, name)',
        'q' => "name='" . $name . "2023.zip' and trashed = false"
    );
    $results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);
    
    // delete latest version already on drive
    if(count($results->getFiles()) == 1) {
        $service->files->delete($results->getFiles()[0]->getId(), array('supportsAllDrives' => true));
    }
    
    //upload on drive of the new version
    $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $file->setName($name); // name of the file
    $file->setMimeType('application/zip'); // type
    $file->setParents(['***']); // id of shared drive

    $data = file_get_contents("path"); // path to file (hidden for the question)

    $createdFile = $service->files->create($file, array(
        'data' => $data,
        'mimeType' => 'application/zip',
        'uploadType' => 'multipart',
        'supportsAllDrives' => true
    ));
} else {
    // name saving
    file_put_contents('code.txt', $_GET['name']);
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . $authUrl);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Can you check the Shared Drive in the Google Drive UI and check if you have `Manager` or `Content manager` permission? I understand that the file you're trying to delete is in a Shared Drive correct?

Comment: I have `Content manager` and yes it's a shared drive @LorenaGomez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what is the issue, I tested deleting a file from a Shared Drive as a `Content manager` and I get the same error you mentioned, I'm only able to delete the file from the Google Drive UI.

Reading through the documentation for the `files.delete` method, it says:

> If the file belongs to a shared drive the user must be an organizer on the parent.

So this means that through the Drive API we're not able to delete files as `Content manager`, the currently authenticated user must be an organizer on the parent for the Shared Drive file.

The documentations says that as a `Content manager` you can "By default, can upload, edit, move, or delete all files." but it seems this will only work if you do it through the Google Drive UI.

If you want to provide a feedback regarding this behavior, you can submit it through [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/support#developer_product_feedback).

## References:

- [Method: files.delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/delete)
- [Type of members](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/7286514?visit_id=637042405228053249-956633332&p=team_drives&rd=1#:%7E:text=your%20administrator.-,Types%20of%20members,-Manager%3A%20Can%20manage)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'll submit the feedback!